# Generalized lenses definition

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to understand what Spivak says at time 6:09 of [this YouTube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=U-W7GT0BUTU) but I am not sure what he means by his $f^*$ notation. I will describe the issue fully here, to make this question self contained. For a category $\mathbb{C},$ Spivak starts with a functor $A:{\mathbb C}^{\text op} \rightarrow \text{Cat}$ (which he seems to call a generalized lens setup), and then he "takes the Grothendieck construction of $A$" (a notion I am unfamiliar with), and obtains a category he calls $\text{Lens}_A.$ I want to understand the nature of $\text{Lens}_A.$ Spivak says that the objects of $\text{Lens}_A$ are pairs $(c,a)$ where $c$ is an object of $\mathbb{C},$ and $a$ is an object of $A(c).$ Also (and this is the part I am confused about) Spivak says that a morphism in $\text{Lens}_A$ from $(c,a)$ to $(c',a')$ consists of a pair $(f,f^\#)$ where $f:c \rightarrow c'$ and $f^\# :f^* a' \rightarrow a.$ My main question is, what is $f^*$ ? Spivak does not define the $f^*$ notation here.

Answer (score 1):

$f^*$ is just a different notation for $A(f)$ here. You can read about the construction here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_construction
- https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction